Why do I get a secondary IP address with DHCP?
I don't know why my pikvm gets 2 ip addresses for the wlan0.
It's the only device that gets 2 in my entire network.
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether d8:3a:dd:*:*:* brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.111.201/24 metric 50 brd 192.168.111.255 scope global dynamic wlan0
       valid_lft 14113sec preferred_lft 14113sec
    inet 192.168.111.27/24 brd 192.168.111.255 scope global secondary dynamic noprefixroute wlan0
       valid_lft 14120sec preferred_lft 12320sec


How can I prevent it?
I've already added net.ipv4.conf.wlan0.promote_secondaries=1
ip link set wlan0 down then up solves it but not at boot.

You probably have two DHCP clients running. If they send different Client-ID options, they will obtain different IP addresses for the same interface.
(For example, many DHCP clients use a MAC-address-based Client-ID, but systemd-networkd instead uses one that is based on /etc/machine-id, while dhcpcd uses one based on dhcpcd.duid. Even though the MAC address is the same, 3 different Client-IDs would get 3 different leases.)
Run systemctl status or journalctl -b and look through your services for anything network-related that looks like it's responsible for DHCP.
